# How to iterate through the Enrollments navigation property of Student with EFCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using EFCore that seems to be unable to do lazy-loading in the current release.

My models are defined as follows:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}


public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}


public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

In `Details.cshtml` I want to iterate through the `Enrollments` of a student as follows.

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Student
<h2>Details</h2>
<dl>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Enrollments)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Course Title</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Enrollments)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Course.Title)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Grade)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

However, I got the following errors.

[image]

## Questions

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is **lazy loading**. It is not supported by EF Core *yet*. [Source](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#lazy-loading)

What you need to do, is when querying the database, use Include() to do **eager loading**.

So something like this:

```
var student = context.Students
                     .Include(s => s.Enrollments)
                     .ThenInclude(e => e.Course)
                     .FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
```

Comment: See my edit. You can use ThenInclude() to include data from a deeper level.